# Arduino not saving to SD correctly

Tags: arduino

I've built simple project with my daughter that takes two temp readings and writes the to a file on a Micro SD card.

The code is fairly simple (if not a bit messy) and is creating the file, but only ever seems to write the same row of data twice (from the setup()) and then never writes again, although doesn't seem to produce an error.

The code is:

```
#include <Wire.h> //Required for Realtime Clock
#include "RTClib.h" //Required for Realtime Clock
#include <SPI.h> //Required for SD card reader
#include <SD.h>  //Required for SD card reader

#include <dht11.h> //Required for Temp/humidity reader

#define DHTPIN 4  //Pin for temp sensor
#define LEDPIN 7  //Pin for led (status)
#define DHTTYPE DHT11 //define which temp sensor we are using (DHT11)

dht11 DHT11; //Create instance of DHT11 class to read sensor values
File myFile;
String filename;

uint32_t  start_min; //Store time the current loop started so we can work out how long we've been running for
RTC_DS3231 RTC;  //Create instance of real Time clock class

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);  //start serial monitor for output
  Wire.begin();

  //begin the rtc, let us know if it fails
  if (! RTC.begin()) {
    Serial.println("Couldn't find RTC");
    abort();
  }

  Serial.print("Initializing SD card...");
  if (!SD.begin(10)) {
    Serial.println("initialization failed!");
    while (1);
  }

  Serial.println("initialization done.");
  //set RTC time and date to the time the app was compiled
  RTC.adjust(DateTime(__DATE__, __TIME__));

  //Get the current RTC time and sore it as a unix time
  DateTime now = RTC.now();
  start_min = now.unixtime();

  //Setup Filename
  String filename = String(start_min);
  int start = filename.length() - 8;
  int end = filename.length();
  filename = filename.substring(2,10) + ".csv";
  Serial.println(filename);

  //Write Header row
  myFile = SD.open(filename, FILE_WRITE);
  if(myFile) {
    myFile.println("timestamp|humidity|temperature1|temperature2");
    myFile.flush();
    myFile.close();
    delay(1000);
  }
  else {
    Serial.println("Error opening file");
  }
}

void loop() {

  //Get current RTC date and time
  DateTime now = RTC.now(); 

  //Convert to unix time
  uint32_t _now = now.unixtime();

 // work out if  x mins have passed
  if((_now - start_min) > (4*60)) {
    //Turn LED on
    digitalWrite(LEDPIN,HIGH);
    Serial.print("Looped - ");
    Serial.print(now.hour());
    Serial.print(":");
    Serial.println(now.minute());

    int chk = DHT11.read(DHTPIN);

    myFile = SD.open(filename, FILE_WRITE);
    if(myFile) {

      String output = String(now.getTimeStr());
      output += "|";
      output += String((float)DHT11.humidity,2);
      output += "|";
      output += String((float)DHT11.temperature, 2);
      output += "|";
      output += String(RTC.getTemperature());
      Serial.println(output);

      myFile.println(output);
      myFile.close();

      Serial.println("Write complete");
    } 
    else {
      Serial.println("Error opening file");
    }

    //reset start time
    start_min = now.unixtime();

  }

    delay(5000);
   //Turn LED off
   digitalWrite(LEDPIN,0);
   //wait 90 secs
   delay(5000);
}
```

I'm using an Arduino Uno, a DHT11 for temp/humidity and a DS3231 RTC (also grabbing temp there to).

Once compiled and uploaded. this is the output:

```
Sketch uses 16798 bytes (52%) of program storage space. Maximum is 32256 bytes.

Global variables use 1290 bytes (62%) of dynamic memory, leaving 758 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2048 bytes.
```

any help appreciate

Comment: You seem to be using quite a bit of RAM with this sketch.  You're at 62% with just your global variables.  Every time you use the + operator on a String you have to reallocate for the whole String.  The String class is a big memory hog.  One thing that might be worth trying would be to use char arrays or at least stop concatenating everything into one string before you print it.  Just print the individual pieces one by one.  That gets the same result faster and uses less RAM.  Would actually be best to use char arrays and get away from the String class on a memory limited system.  Up to you.

Comment: You can also reduce RAM usage quite a bit by using the F macro when printing constant strings.  Serial.println(F("Some constant string"));  Google that for more info.

Comment: You're also wasting your time converting the temperature and humidity to a float before you print it.  Why are you doing that?  The library has them as int (unless you're not using the library I think you are) and converting an int to a float doesn't gain anything.  If you just want a ".00" printed after it then just print that directly   Serial.print(humidity);  Serial.println(".00");  There's no need to waste resources converting that to a float just to get a couple of zeroes stuck on it.

Comment: Wow, this is brilliant, thank you. I'll go through and try these things and see if that helps.  In terms of the floats, these we just taken from an example I found for the DHT11 although the example for Serial printing.  Thanks for taking the time to write all of this up for me